VScodeでPHPデバッグする方法
環境
ホストOS:Windows11 Pro
VM:VMware
ゲストOS:ubuntu 22.04 LTS
ゲストOS内の環境
VScode:ver 1.96.2
Docker:ver 24.0.7
docker-compose: ver 1.29.2
php: ver 8.1.2-1
やりたいこと
ゲストOS上で、VScodeによるPHPファイルのデバッグステップ実行をしたいです。
試したこと
./php-debugをカレントとして、以下を実行。
docker-compose up -d --build

VScodeでデバッガを起動してステップ実行させるにはどうすればよいでしょうか？
ディレクトリツリーと各ファイルの中身
./php_debug/
├── .vscode
│   └── launch.json
├── docker
│   ├── nginx
│   │   └── default.conf
│   └── php
│       ├── Dockerfile
│       └── php.ini
├── docker-compose.yml
└── src
    ├── js
    │   └── upload.js
    ├── lib
    │   └── jquery-3.7.1.min.js
    ├── php
    │   └── uploadconfig.php
    └── upload.html

.vscode/launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "hostname": "0.0.0.0",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html/": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
            },
            "log":true
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9000,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}

./docker/nginx/default.conf
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php;

  location / {
    root /var/www/html;
    index upload.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_pass app:9000; 
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}

./docker/php/Dockerfile
FROM php:8.2-fpm

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    zip \
    unzip 
    
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

WORKDIR /var/www

./docker/php/php.ini
[PHP]
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
variables_order = EGPCS

[xdebug]
zend_extension = xdebug.so
xdebug.mode = develop,debug
xdebug.start_with_request = trigger
xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.discover_client_host = yes
xdebug.remote_enable=1

./docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.25.0
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - app
  # PHP-FPMの定義
  app:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
     - ./src:/var/www/html   
  # mysql:

./src/upload.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <script src="./lib/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/upload.js"></script>
    <title>Testing PHP Debug</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div  class="container">
        <h1>Debugging PHP</h1>
      </div>
    </header>

    <main>
      <div class="control">
        <section>
          <form method="post">
            <input id="upload" type="file" name="upfile" size="30">
            <button id="file_upload" disabled>送信</button>
          </form>
        </section>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>

./src/js/upload.js
$(function(){
  $('#file_upload')
    .on('click', function(){
      window.alert('clicked')
  });

  $('#upload').on('change',function(){
    $($('input[type=file]')[1]).val("");

    var file = $($('input[type=file]')[0]).prop('files')[0];

    this.loadingok = false;
    this.rebootFg = 0;
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append($($('input[type=file]')[0]).attr('name'), file);

    $.ajax({
      url: './php/uploadconfig.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      if(data == "0") {
        $('#file_upload').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#file_upload').off();
      }else{
        $('input[type=file]').val("");
        $('#file_upload').off();
        $('#file_upload').attr('disabled', 'true');
        alert("アップロードに失敗しました。");
      }
    });
  });
});

./src/php/uploadconfig.php
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'ja_JP.UTF-8');

if(isset($_FILES["upfile"]) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"])) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"], $UPLOADDIR . $_FILES["upfile"]["name"])) {
        chmod($UPLOADDIR . $_FILES["upfile"]["name"], 0644);
        echo "0";
        return;
    }
}

echo "1";

?>


自己解決したので、投稿します。
php.iniにxdebug2の時の記述が残っており正常動作を妨げていたようです。
xdebug.remote_enable=1 の行を削除します。
[PHP]
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
variables_order = EGPCS

[xdebug]
zend_extension = xdebug.so
; リモートデバッグ有効化
xdebug.mode = develop, debug
; リモートデバッグの自動開始
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
; ホスト指定
xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal
; ホスト側のポート指定
xdebug.client_port = 9003

xdebug.discover_client_host = yes
xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log

